# Git svn clone does not get everything from SVN repo

Tags: git, svn

I used the command git svn clone to retrive the SVP repository.
It finished his job but I noticed a lot of "tags" are not retrieved.
Is there a way to fix that ?
For instance I have a path like "\tags\1_PRD\Portail_PLM_V1.18.00_PRD" but nothing on the GIT side.
But another path from SVN like "svn/tags/1_PRD" (which is a part of previous one) is migrated (even if this path lead to fake version, yes I know, previous repo was bad...).

If I run the command `git for-each-ref` I do not get anything.
It only "worked" the first time I ran it.

The refs are not listed `git show-refs`, or course.

How can I "force" the conversion of the missing refs ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a svn standard layout?

Comment: Yes it is : trunk / branches / tags

Comment: `\tags\1_PRD\Portail_PLM_V1.18.00_PRD` doesn't look according to _standard_ layout. You would need to add `\tags\1_PRD` as a directory to pull tags for git svn (check `.gitconfig` and see how the standard directory for tags is set and then add another rule for the tags in this other directory, then run a new `git svn fetch`).

Comment: I will check that. Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know how to write refspec for git/git svn as I always use GUI so...
My clone is messed up I need to reclone it completely from scratch (hours of process... yeah...) in the mean time I wil ltry something like that:

[svn-remote "svn"]
 url = THE_URL
 fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn <-- Default one whene I ran git svn ini/clone I guess
 fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn/tags/1_PRD* <-- the one I added

Still strange it cannot parse all sub folders directly...

Comment: a `fetch` rule points to a single branch **root directory**. If you want to point at the tags inside `\tags\1_PRD`, you need to provide a `tags` rule (so that all its **subdirectories**, each one separately, are treated like an individual tag). Also, each one of the rules (fetch, branches, tags) has two parts: local (in svn repo) path and what the reference will be like in git. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_configuration

Comment: Thanks for the doc, I was searching for it but only found the "standard" one (not SVN related).